# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.22.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-functions-core-tools

I have recently cloned a new repository which has AzureFunctions but I am unable to run it. The build succeeds and on Run click it opens a window suggesting that it is downloading Azure

I am using VS2017 and .Net core 2.1.

It seems to be working for other team members but not for me.

I keep getting this 'Could not find Azure.WebJobs.Host...' error continuously.

[image: Azure.WebJobs.Host error Screen shot]

I've tried all the fixes that are there on the internet without any luck.

[image: Extensions and Updates screen shot]

The Azure Functions and Web job tools dlls seem to be up-to-date as they are not shown in the updates tab.

[image]

Updating all the nuget dependencies also did not work.
[image: Version of Azure Functions & Web Jobs]

Answer (score 1):

I tried  using VS2017 and .Net core 2.1.

Installed Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs - 3.022 version from Nuget Packages.

[image]
Included Namespace

```
 using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
```

I found that there is no `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host` direct assembly to include.

If  you install  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` you can directly use `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host` namespace.
[image]

Check your .csproj , if you have any PackageReference Included with `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host`, try to remove and build your Application.

[image]

It must include  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`